# I need to iterate through an Eleventy collecting using a Pug template

Tags: javascript, html, pug, liquid, eleventy

I had a working template in nunjucks that I need to convert to pug, but Eleventy is having trouble reading the template.

```
<ul>
    {% for email in collections.emails %}
    <li><a href="{{ email.url }}">{{ email.data.subject }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In Pug, I've expressed this as:

```
ul
    each email of collections.emails
      li: a(href="#{email.url}") #{email.data.subject}
```

...but I'm getting the error: `collections.emails is not iterable`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your error says collections.markdowns, not emails. I can't recreate this myself in Pug.

Comment: Oops. I copied the wrong message. Updated. 

Is there’s a correct way to iterate through a collection? It’s not documented.

Comment: Is there any way you can share your code? when I tried to iterate over a collection in Pug, it worked just fine.

Comment: @RaymondCamden - Are you able to share an example?

Comment: I don't have my code in front of me but it was literally the same. What if you remove the link from the HTML - just to simplify? Also, email.data.subject - are you sure it exists in data - are you sure data exists in email? If you iterate and just output foo, do you see the right number of foos?